# Validate Response which contain only message in Response Body

Tags: java, rest-assured

We are testing API Automation with Rest Assured in Java.
In Postman, we run API after success gives message as "Record Saved Successfully"

Trying to automate the same. How to validate only message recieve as response in body.

```
response.then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
.and().body("$", "Record Saved Successfully");
```

its not working, Please help

Comment: According to the docs you can get the response as a string `String body = response.getBody().asString();` and just assert the strings are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in assertion mechanism:

```
response
      .then()
      .assertThat()
      .statusCode(200)
      .body("message", equalTo("Record Saved Successfully"));
```